# Opencart 3.0: Get the 'Product_Id' of the Last Item Added To Cart

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, opencart-3

I'm working with Opencart 3.0 to set up a product cross-sell to display similar items to the user when they add something to the cart. I thought I had seen a pattern with the array of products in the cart that put the last item of cart at the end. So my php looked something like this:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');

$related_product_id = $products;
$related_product_id = end($related_product_id);
$related_product_id = $related_product_id['product_id'];

$related = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductRelated($related_product_id);

foreach ($related as $related) { 
      //..do something
    }
```

Using the `end()` method in the above code would take the very last `Key=>Value` (Product_id) in the array so I could use it to display the product on the page.

This worked for a while until I noticed that it was not always accurate. If someone added something already in the cart, it wouldn't place it at the end of the array, and also other certain products for some reason didn't show up at the end of the array.

Is there another way to get the `Product_Id` of the last item a user added to the cart than the way I'm going about it? My way doesn't seem very consistent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figured it out adding my own function to `/system/libray/cart/cart.php`

I added this function

```
public function getProductsInCart() {
        $product_data = array();

        $cart_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE api_id = '" . (isset($this->session->data['api_id']) ? (int)$this->session->data['api_id'] : 0) . "' AND customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND session_id = '" . $this->db->escape($this->session->getId()) . "' ORDER BY date_added ASC");

        foreach ($cart_query->rows as $cart) {
                
                $product_data[] = array(
                    'cart_id'         => $cart['cart_id'],
                    'product_id'      => $cart['product_id'],
                    'date_added'      => $cart['date_added'],
                );
        
        }

        return $product_data;
    }
```

And instead of using the `$this->cart->getProducts()` line to get products from the cart, I'm using my new function `$this->cart->getProductsInCart()`.

This works way more consistent. The only thing it doesn't take into consideration is when someone goes back to a product already added. It doesn't count it as a new product added, but instead just updates it quantity.

Let me know if someone finds a better solution.